# Using titles in C.V

Tags: cv

I am going to prepare an updates C.V. Regarding the advisor of my Ph.D thesis, what is better to write about the title of my advisor. I would like to know whether it is common to put `Prof.` in front of the names of advisors or not?

Comment: This depends on local usage. In the US it would be quite different than in Germany.

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: In fact I want to send CV to several different countries such as UK and Norway

Comment: I can't see how putting their title in front of their names could hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. The only thing that they will be looking at is the person's name (either to google it or because they recognise it). If it isn't common practice where you are sending it, they will forgive the difference because you are applying from abroad.

Note: Totally normal in the UK but also fine to not include the title. We don't really care.